# which of the following statements are true or false?

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

let $f_n(x)$, for $n\ge 1$, be a sequence of continuous non negative functions on $[0,1]$, such that

$$\ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x) \, dx=0.$$

which of the following statements is always correct?

A. $f_n\to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$

b. $f_n$ may not converge uniformly but converges pointwise.

c. $f_n$ will converge pointwise and limit may be non zero.

d. $f_n$ is not guaranteed to have a pointwise limit.

can anyone help me to solve above problem.

i know that if $f_n$ converges uniformly then limit of interal converges to interal of limit.

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: i have taken $f_n(x)= \frac{x}{n+1}$. it comes out uniformly convergent

Comment: You forgot the limits of integration!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Wouldn't your answer have worked if you had simply chosen $e^{-nx}$?

Comment: Although that implies (c).  I guess you could go with $\sqrt{n} e^{-nx}$, but that's less succinct.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

If $f_n(x)=(1-x)^n$, then

$$\int_0^1 (1-x)^n\,dx =\frac{1}{n+1}\to 0 \,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty$$

But

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1&,x=0\\\\0&,1\ge x>0\end{cases}$$

and therefore, the convergence of $f_n(x)$ is clearly not uniform.

**SPOLIER ALERT** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> If $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)g(x)$,where $g(x)$ is continuously differentiable, then it is easy to show that  $$\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx\to 0$$(use the [Riemann Lebesgue Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) or integrate by parts).  Noting that $\lim f_n(x)$ fails to exist for $x\ne 0$ and we conclude the answer is (d) $f_n$ is not guaranteed to have a pointwise limit.

Comment: yes now i left with last two options.

Comment: thanks. any idea about last two?

Comment: Try $f_n(x)=g(x)\sin(nx)$ for any differentiable $g$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is (d) in case you still can not see it by considering the function

> $$  \sin(nx) . $$

Comment: no i think there is a problem

Comment: $e^{nx}$ donot satisfy integral condition

Comment: intergal going to infinity

Comment: Study the new function.

Comment: @Downvoter: It is corrected!

Comment: @user290972:  Do not get misled by the downvote!

Comment: @user290972: I gave you the right answer!  Not to be misled the answer to your question is $(d) $.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Take for the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ a hill which is  getting narrower, rolling around and around in the interval $(0,1)$ and such that it's integral is equal to a sequence of reals converging to $0$. I let you write a precise case of such a sequence of functions.

$(f_n)$ doesn't converge pointwise proving that all four assumptions are wrong.